# How pass a struct as an argument in call from python code

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

How call this contract functions from python code?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract MY_PERSONS {

    struct Person{
        string name;
        uint age;
    }

    Person[] private persons;

    constructor ( Person[] _persons ) public {
    // persons = _persons; // not yet supported
    for(uint i=0; i<_persons.length; i++)
        persons.push(_persons[i]);
    }

    function add_person(Person _person) public  {
        persons.push(_person);
    }

    function get_person(uint index) public view returns(Person) {
        require(index >=0 && index < persons.length);
        return persons[index];
    }

}
```

I tested [Contract Deployment Example](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html)
and [Passing Struct as an argument in call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65980/passing-struct-as-an-argument-in-call) and everything was OK, but I don't know how call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a working code on remix. It is recommended to use `memory` keyword for the `struct` parameter.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;  
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

    contract HelloWorld {

        struct User {
            string name;
            uint age;
        }

        User[] users;


        function addUser(User memory user_) public  {
            users.push(user_);
        }

        function getUser(uint index) public view returns(User memory) {
             require(index >=0 && index < users.length);
           return users[index];
        }
    }
```

---

```
user = ["hello", 10];
HelloWorld.transact().addUser(user);
```

Comment: I use `user = ["hello", 10];` also `user = ("hello", 10);` but this error occurre: **ValueError: No matching entries for 'tuple' in encoder registry**

Comment: Did you use on remix?

Comment: No, I use web3py and py-solc to compile solidity code like [this](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html)

Comment: You might try with the `web3 v5 beta`. tuples might not be supported in `v4`. @H.Mohseni