# How to signTransaction of a smart contract methods?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a smart contract contains this method:

```
function addOneUser (User memory _user) public {

         bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(_user.name));
         users[hash] = _user;

    }
```

I want to invoke this method using singTransaction then sendSignedTransaction,
how to encode data (which _user) into transaction raw ?

Comment: See [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/73705/16043).

Answer (score -1):

In current versions of Solidity you cannot send `struct` type parameters to the methods unless you use experimental mode using this statement in the header:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

You should see this question for more details:
[Passing Struct as an argument in call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65980/passing-struct-as-an-argument-in-call)

Comment: the question about signing a transaction, the code above is not the full smart contract, unless you can say also: "you can not declare function outside contract {...}"